# How does Manipulate work "under the hood", i.e. gets converted into DynamicModule and Dynamic?

Tags: manipulate, dynamic

The Mathematica documentation says in [Introduction to Dynamic](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IntroductionToDynamic.html) under "Dynamic and Other Functions":

> `Manipulate` in fact produces a combination of `Dynamic`, controls, and formatting constructs, not fundamentally different from what you can do yourself using these lower-level functions.

And in [Advanced Dynamic Functionality](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AdvancedDynamicFunctionality.html) under "Nested Dynamics" it says:

> the output of `Manipulate` consists of a highly complex set of interrelated and nested `Dynamic` expressions

From other places (e.g. the documentation for [Panel](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Panel.html) under "Properties & Relations" states "The `Manipulate` construct uses `Panel`"), I gather that

```
Manipulate[x + y, {x, 0, 9, 1}, {y, 0, 90, 10}]
```

works and looks a bit like

```
DynamicModule[{x, y},
 Panel[Column[{
    Grid[{{"x", Manipulator[Dynamic[x], {0, 9, 1}]},
      {"y", Manipulator[Dynamic[y], {0, 90, 10}]}
      }],
    Pane[
     Framed[Style[Dynamic[x + y], "Output"], FrameMargins -> 15, 
      Background -> White, FrameStyle -> LightGray]]
    }]
  ]
 ]
```

- What code gets really generated for a `Manipulate` expression?
- Where (in the documentation, or elsewhere) can I find that?
- Can I somehow see or obtain the code generated for a specific `Manipulate` inside Mathematica?

Comment: maybe `Trace[Manipulate[{}, {a, 0, 1}]] // Column`?

Comment: I’m also curious about this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a very broad question (too many controls, options, etc.), but one can find out what the output is equivalent to like this:

```
Manipulate[x + y, {x, 0, 9, 1}, {y, 0, 90, 10}] //
    MakeBoxes[#, StandardForm] & // First //
  ToExpression // InputForm

(*
DynamicModule[{
  x = 0, y = 0,
  Typeset`show = True,
  Typeset`bookmarkList = {},
  Typeset`bookmarkMode = "Menu",
  Typeset`animator,
  Typeset`animvar = 1,
  Typeset`name = "\"untitled\"",
  Typeset`specs = {{Hold[x], 0, 9, 1}, {Hold[y], 0, 90, 10}},
  Typeset`size = Automatic,
  Typeset`update = 0,
  Typeset`initDone = False,
  Typeset`skipInitDone = True},
 Dynamic[
  RawBoxes[
   Manipulate`ManipulateBoxes[1, StandardForm,
    "Variables" :> {x = 0, y = 0},
    "ControllerVariables" :> {}, 
    "OtherVariables" :> {Typeset`show, Typeset`bookmarkList, 
      Typeset`bookmarkMode, Typeset`animator, Typeset`animvar, 
      Typeset`name, Typeset`specs, Typeset`size, Typeset`update, 
      Typeset`initDone, Typeset`skipInitDone},
    "Body" :> x + y,
    "Specifications" :> {{x, 0, 9, 1}, {y, 0, 90, 10}},
    "Options" :> {},
    "DefaultOptions" :> {}]
   ],
  SingleEvaluation -> True],
 DynamicModuleValues :> {},
 Deinitialization :> None,
 UntrackedVariables :> {Typeset`size},
 SynchronousInitialization -> True,
 UnsavedVariables :> {Typeset`initDone}, 
 UndoTrackedVariables :> {Typeset`show, Typeset`bookmarkMode}]
*)
```

You can then execute the

```
Manipulate`ManipulateBoxes[ ...] // ToExpression // InputForm
```

which is held by `Dynamic` to see what gets created dynamically (it's long) when the `Manipulate` is running.

But there's a whole 'nother process for instantiating a `DynamicModule` in the FrontEnd that creates a unique module with unique `DynamicModule` variables.  (When you copy/paste the output of `Manipulate`, you basically copy/paste the structure above.  When the output form of it appears in the Front End, the instantiation process is invoked and you get an interactive `Manipulate` applet.

The "Tutorials" menu on the documentation page of `Manipulate` has links to the four introductory/advanced tutorials on `Dynamic` and `Manipulate`, which is the principal documentation.  They are more of a user's manual than a complete technical documentation, however.